# SQL Statement order by maximum of entries

Tags: php, sql, statements

I have a table called "reports"

it looks like:

```
user_id | report_post 
   1            2    
   2            2  
   3            2  
   4           10
```

Now I want to list the first three entries at first, cause the reported post id "2" is 3 times in this table... i want so sort them by the maximum of entries.

Hope you guys understand... thanks alot

----edit------
my output have to look like this

```
report_post | entries
    2             3    
   10             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, report_post, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reports
    GROUP BY report_post
) c
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select report_post, Count(1) As Entries
From   reports
Group By Report_Post
Order By Count(1) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery. This should do the trick in MySQL:

```
select * from reports 
order by (
   select count(*) from reports as reports_a
   where reports_a.report_post=reports.report_post
) desc;
```

(the above answer's your question before you edited it to change it's meaning)

For the edited question, it is a trivial example of a group by:

```
select report_post,count(*) as entries
from reports
group by report_post
order by entries desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

With your edit, this does what you're asking:

```
select report_post, count(*) entries
from reports
group by report_post
order by entries desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT report_post as report_post, count(report_post) as entries 
FROM `reports` group by `report_post`
```

Single query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM reports ORDER BY entries DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what exactly you are asking. Are you just trying to get it to return entries where the report_post id is equal to "2"?

If that is the case, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE report_post=2;
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: It might have been good to post the first part (question about where you are unclear of the posters intent) on the question as a comment.